# select2 jquery plugin resets select element that have pre selected Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using the [Select2](https://select2.github.io) tag input jQuery plugin.

I call select items and preselected items via two **json** formatted variables and using **initSelection** option to set preselected Items.

All things work perfectly, but when I choose a new item from the select box, previous items are removed from it.

How can I solve this problem?

```
var allTags = [{
    "tag_id": 1,
    "tag_title": "Laravel"
}, {
    "tag_id": 3,
    "tag_title": "jQuery"
}, {
    "tag_id": 4,
    "tag_title": "HTML"
}];

var postTags = ["tag_id": 3, "tag_title": "jQuery"
}, {
        "tag_id": 4,
        "tag_title": "HTML"
    }
    }];
var allTags = $.map(allTags, function (obj) {
    obj.id = obj.id || obj.tag_id;
    obj.text = obj.text || obj.tag_title;
    return obj;
});

var postTag = $.map(postTags, function (obj) {
    obj.id = obj.id || obj.tag_id;
    obj.text = obj.text || obj.tag_title;
    return obj;
});

$('[id^="meta_keywords"]').select2({
    dir: "rtl",
    tags: true,
    initSelection: function (element, callback) {
        callback(postTag);
    },
    data: allTags
});
```

This is a JsFiddle Example:

[See On JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uv2sfpp/)

Comment: It looks like what is happening is you have "HTML", "jQuery" pre-selected, but the drop down list is not reflecting that. Clicking on an already selected item, it gets toggled on/off. Clicking "Laravel" will add it to the selected options and not remove anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-select when clicking on a previously selected item will deselect it. The initSelection code is not required, you can make them pre-selected in the data section

http://jsfiddle.net/ncjo6bz1/

```
var allTags = [{
    "tag_id": 1,
        "tag_title": "Laravel",
}, {
    "tag_id": 3,
        "tag_title": "jQuery",
    selected: true
}, {
    "tag_id": 4,
        "tag_title": "HTML",
    selected: true
}];

var allTags = $.map(allTags, function (obj) {
    obj.id = obj.id || obj.tag_id;
    obj.text = obj.text || obj.tag_title;
    obj.selected = obj.selected || false;

    return obj;
});

$('[id^="meta_keywords"]').select2({
    dir: "rtl",
    tags: true,
    data: allTags

});
```

I was unable to find a better way but if you want to hide already selected items from the drop down, some CSS can do that

```
li.select2-results__option[aria-selected='true'] {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ncjo6bz1/2/